# Triangle inequality for integrals with complex valued integrand

Tags: integration, measure-theory, inequality

This is a step in a lecture note I'm reading. It should be simple because the author considers it obvious but I can't see it. What am I missing?

Suppose $U$ and $V$ are integrable over measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$. Claim:
$$
\int_\Omega\sqrt{U^2+V^2}d\mu\geq\sqrt{\left(\int_\Omega Ud\mu\right)^2+\left(\int_\Omega Vd\mu\right)^2}.
$$
Alternative phrasing: with $Z=U+iV$, claim that 
$$
\int_\Omega|Z|d\mu\geq\left|\int_\Omega Zd\mu\right|.
$$
Thank you for your time!

Comment: I allowed myself to change the title of your question, so that it can be found easier using the search function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second can be shown as follows (I like the "trick" used here):

Choose $\alpha \in \Bbb{C}$, $|\alpha| = 1$ such that (why is there such an $\alpha$?)

$$
\alpha \cdot \int_\Omega Z\,d\mu = \left|\int_\Omega Z\,d\mu\right|.
$$

Then (because the left hand side is a real number)

$$
\left| \int_\Omega Z\,d\mu\right| = \rm{Re}\left(\int_\Omega \alpha Z \,d\mu\right)  = \int_\Omega \rm{Re}(\alpha Z)\,d\mu \leq \int_\Omega |\alpha Z|\,d\mu = \int_\Omega |Z|\,d\mu.
$$

The first form follows.

Comment: Neat trick. I will remember it. Thanks. :)