# Prove $|(f, g)| \leq \int |f \bar g|$ for Complex Cases

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $f, g$ be $\mathbb C$-valued functions defined on $\mathbb R$ and $f, g \in L^2$. To prove the inequality in this title, I proceed as follows but got a weaker bound. Recall that $\mathrm{Re}\ a \leq |a|$ and $\mathrm{Im}\ a \leq |a|, \forall a \in \mathbb C$.

$$\left|(f, g)\right| = \left|\int f\bar g \right| = \left|\int \mathrm{Re}\ f\bar g  + i\int\mathrm{Im}\ f\bar g\right| = \sqrt{\left(\int \mathrm{Re}\ f\bar g\right)^2 + \left(\int\mathrm{Im}\ f\bar g\right)^2} \leq \sqrt{\left(\int \left|f\bar g\right|\right)^2 + \left(\int\left |f\bar g\right| \right)^2} = \sqrt{2}\int\left |f\bar g\right|.$$

How do I get the desired bound, please? Thank you!

Comment: Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be measure space. Then $|\int_{X}f d\mu|\leq \int_{X}|f| du$; for $f\in L^{1}(\mu).$

Comment: @Inquisitive Showing THIS seems to be the question, right?

Comment: @Inquisitive Sorry I do not see how to use your inequality to prove my inequality. Could you show more steps, please?

Comment: @20824; $f,g\in L^{2}$, so $f\bar{g}\in L^{1};$ now $|\int_{X}f\bar{g} d\mu| \leq \int_{X} |f\bar{g}| d\mu;$

Comment: @Inquisitive Sorry for the misleading, I updated that $f, g \in L^2$. Why is $f \bar g$ in $L^1$?

Comment: @20824; Applies Schwartz inequality(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality);

Comment: This http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842739/probably-simple-application-of-holder-or-minkowski-for-integrals/842745#842745 should answer your question.

Comment: $f\overline{g}\in L^{1}$ because $|f\overline{g}|=|f||g|\le \frac{1}{2}(|f|^{2}+|g|^{2})$.